# TextView and Button in a row of listview xamarin

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I need a listview in which i have a textview and a button in a row in Xamarin using c#.
the button will be enabled/disabled based on the value of text in textview.
i have to use SetAdapter for this . i'm getting the value to put in the textview from a string array . I cant figure out how to create the xml and axml files. I need help!!

Comment: Have you checked out the "Customizing a ListView's Appearance" page on the Xamarin site: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview's_appearance/ It has some good information.  I think you would be interested in the "Creating Custom Row Layouts" section about half way down the page.

Comment: what did you tried? post it.